# How to install Acrotex in Debian for TeXLive?

Tags: debian, software-installation, latex

I need LaTeX Eforms, which is part of the package *[Acrotex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex)* which zip-file [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex.zip), for my TeXLive 2017. 
It is not part of Debian TeXLive because the package is not free enough for Debian, stated by Ulrike [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385577/13173). 
There is no installation instructions in the package. 
The online website has the phrase *macros/latex/contrib/acrotex*, so maybe, indicating where to install in the filesystem. 
Ulrike's comment about installing but I really would like to have a confirmation in my Vanilla system with `equivs` control [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373898/13173) such that I do not mess up my TeXLive installation.

> You can get the miktex package http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/acrotex.tar.lzma You only need to unpack it. There are a few files which are documentation, but the rest should simply go in your local texmf in tex/latex/acrotex.

My attempt

1. Find the location of the `texmf-local` in your system by `find / -type d -name "texmf-local" 2>/dev/null`
2. Download the zip-file and unzip it [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex)
3. Move the files to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, since you see it is safe in the following

   ```
   masi@masi:~$ ls /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/
   bibtex  doc  dvips  fonts  metapost  tex  tlpkg  web2c

   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ cd acrotex/texmf/
   doc/    source/ tex/    tpm/
   ```
4. But having a trouble in doing the copying

   ```
   masi@masi:~/Downloads/acrotex/texmf$ mv * /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/
   mv: replace '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc', overriding mode 2755 (rwxr-sr-x)?
   ```
5. Studying the environment

   ```
   masi@masi:~$ ls /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/
   local
   masi@masi:~$ ls /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/local/
   ```
6. Getting `Permission denied` without `sudo`, so

   ```
   masi@masi:~/Downloads/acrotex/texmf$ sudo mv * 
   /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/
   mv: cannot move 'doc' to '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc': Directory not empty
   mv: cannot move 'tex' to '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex': Directory not empty
   ```

Output unsuccesful with the [test code of the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386946/13173).

```
! LaTeX Error: File `eforms.sty' not found.
```

Expected output: output in the thread answer screenshot figure [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386946/13173).

### Testing Ferenc's proposal

Code where `sudo` did not work on the second command

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sudo tar -C "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)" --strip-components=1 -xf acrotex.tar.lzma

masi@masi:~/Downloads$ mktexlsr "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)"
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: Done.
```

Output: `! LaTeX Error: File`eforms.sty' not found.` on test tex file so failure.

Using `sudo` instead with the second command, you get

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sudo mktexlsr "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)"
sudo: mktexlsr: command not found
```

Testing PATHs in my system

```
masi@masi:~$ which mktexlsr
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexlsr

masi@masi:~$ sudo which mktexlsr

masi@masi:~$ sudo -l which mktexlsr
/usr/bin/which mktexlsr
```

### Correct command with correct path (Ferenc)

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexlsr "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)"
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

Output: as expected with the test file!

OS: Debian 9
TeXLive: 2017 manual installation at TeXLive `/usr/local/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Your local texmf" is probably what `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` returns (usually `/usr/local/share/texmf`). So use something like

```
# tar -C "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)" --strip-components=1 -xf acrotex.tar.lzma
# mktexlsr "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)"
```

to unpack and index the package. If the quoted instructions are correct (I haven't checked that), this should make the package available to all users on the system. Alternatively, you can use `TEXMFHOME` instead of `TEXMFLOCAL` to install into your home directory. You may need to create the directory, and don't use `mktexlsr` in this case. This does not require root privileges and does not affect other users, so may be more appropriate for initial testing.

Comment: Use `sudo` for the second command as well. The `#` tried to show that these commands need root privileges.

Comment: Then I think something is badly broken on your system. `mktexlsr` is in `/usr/bin` on Debian systems, and that directory is in the path with and without `sudo`. Please show us the output of `sudo -l` and `which mktexlsr`. Then try running `mktexlsr` under `sudo` with its full path (which was revealed by the `which` command), like for example as `sudo /usr/bin/mktexlsr ...`

Comment: Ah, so you've got a manual TeXLive installation under `/usr/local`! You really should have emphasized this; mentioning the version number alone did not make this clear for me, as Debian stretch has TeXLive 2016.20170123-5. Anyway: try `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexlsr "$(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)"` (this is what I meant by running `mktexlsr` under sudo with its full path). This should update `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R` to index your acrotex installation and make `latex` find `eforms.sty` below that directory.